# How to show page title in master detail page using xaml on xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to show a page title in master detail page using xaml. I tried by adding **x:Name** and **x:Title** attribute inside **MasterDetailPage**, **MasterDetailPage.Master**, **MasterDetailPage.Details** tag. But these did not work. Here is the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MSCommunity_Xamarin"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         x:Class="PrismUnityApp3.Views.MainPage"
         x:Name="Page title">

<MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: try to set title for content page Title=”Menu”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages title are only displayed for pages embedded in a `NavigationPage`, and the property being looked for is `Title` (not x:Title, not x:Name).

It doesn't make a lot of sense to embed a MDP in a NP. The usual pattern is having a bunch of `ContentPage`s (with `Title` set) in a `NavigationPage` set as the `Detail` of the `MasterDetailPage`. The MDP being your `Application.MainPage`